# Short story: man frozen in time seen as a monster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I need help identifying a short science fiction story. I can't remember who the story is by or what it is called.

It is about man who is frozen in time, initially appearing as a blur, but over a long period of time he becomes increasingly substantial. Civilizations rise up around him. Not knowing what he is, they initially see him as a monster. As time goes on their understanding of him evolves.

His predicament is the result of an experiment gone wrong.

I believe it was published sometime between the 1950s and 1970s.

I read a half dozen science fiction anthologies or so recently, and I believe it was from one of those, but after looking through the table of contents in each, I can't find it. Off the top of my head, the anthologies include Harlan Ellison's *Dangerous Visions* (and *Again Dangerous Visions*), David Hartwell's *Science Fiction Century*, *The Big Book of Science Fiction* by Jeff VanderMeer, *The Time Traveler's Almanac* also by VanderMeer, Damon Knight's *A Century of Science Fiction*, and Harry Turtledove's *The Best Time Travel Stories in the 20th Century*).

Comment: Hi there. If you can, please have a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they can trigger any more memories you could edit in. Perhaps most importantly - roughly when would this have been published?

Answer (score 9):

I found it. The story is *The Man Who Walked Home* by James Tiptree Jr. I don't believe it was in any of the anthologies I cited, but rather from her story story collection, *Her Smoke Rose Up Forever*. One small correction: the man was seen as a monster initially, not a god (the question title has been edited to reflect this).